# What's Scala hash function for Strings?

Tags: scala, hash

I am looking for Scala's default hash function for hashing strings, however after some time searching I haven't found it. So, I would like to ask for the help of anyone who knows the source code of the language.

This is the hash function for Java: [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In standard Scala on the JVM, strings are regular Java strings. The hashing function is the same. Additional string operations are made available by an implicit conversion from String to [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps).

In Scala JS there is a custom implementation. I suspect it has the same behavior as the JVM version. [Here's the implementation](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/606b5968daec7b78e9b3b5b7b638181736d7fe2f/library/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/runtime/RuntimeString.scala#L74-L84).

The implementations for other Scala backends may vary (but I'm also not aware of any other actively developed backends).

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that. I guess that answers my question. Many thanks.

Comment: The .NET backend used to be production-ready, but was abandoned a couple of years ago. The native implementation (based on LLVM) receives some interest from time to time, but is a pretty massive undertaking and *very* far from even being a prototype. I don't know of any others. (A native Cocoa backend would be cool.)

Comment: I saw an LLVM backend, recently, for Dotty as well.